# Apply automator action to original instead of copy

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to make a simple action to scale down an image by 50% but keeping an original copy of the file in the same directory.
I easily made an action similar to what I want that produces two files: one original one with the original name, and another scaled with the copy suffix. 
The problem is that I want to have the scaled img with the original file name, and the original img with a "copy" suffix.

This is what my action looks like right now:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I find out a way to do it with variables.
Basically I set a new variable before the duplicate, duplicate the file, get the previously set variable, and then scale the image.